# How can I use Lightroom Preset as filter for photos or video in iOS application?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, gpuimage, lightroom, preset

How to apply a filter to an image via **GPUImage** OR **Core Graphics** or via any other framework from *Lightroom Presets*.

How to use Lightroom Presets' element individually on an image (Contrast, Saturation, Tint, Sharpness,etc..).

Individual Lightroom Preset elements:

[image]

Comment: Please be more clear as to what you are asking? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't an easy task since to use Lightroom presets as filter you need to make an homemade subset of Lightroom.

1: open the preset file with a text editor to investigate on what processing Lightroom use to achieve the effect, is something like

```
value = {
        settings = {
            AutoLateralCA = 0,
            Blacks2012 = 49,
            BlueHue = 11,
            BlueSaturation = 4,
            CameraProfile = "Adobe Standard",
            ChromaticAberrationB = 0,
            ChromaticAberrationR = 0,
            Clarity2012 = 30,
            ColorNoiseReduction = 0,
            ColorNoiseReductionDetail = 50,
            ColorNoiseReductionSmoothness = 50,
            Contrast2012 = 13,
            ConvertToGrayscale = true,
            CropConstrainToWarp = 0,
            Defringe = 0,
            DefringeGreenAmount = 0,
            DefringeGreenHueHi = 60,
            DefringeGreenHueLo = 40,
            DefringePurpleAmount = 0,
            DefringePurpleHueHi = 70,
            DefringePurpleHueLo = 30,
            EnableCalibration = true,
            EnableCircularGradientBasedCorrections = true,
            EnableDetail = true,
            EnableEffects = true,
            EnableGradientBasedCorrections = true,
            EnableGrayscaleMix = true,
            EnableLensCorrections = true,
            EnableSplitToning = true,
            Exposure2012 = 0,
            GrainAmount = 0,
            GrainFrequency = 50,
            GrainSize = 25,
            GrayMixerAqua = 4,
            GrayMixerBlue = -14,
            GrayMixerGreen = -11,
            GrayMixerMagenta = 3,
            GrayMixerOrange = -3,
            GrayMixerPurple = 13,
            GrayMixerRed = 8,
            GrayMixerYellow = -6,
            GreenHue = 26,
            GreenSaturation = -1,
            Highlights2012 = -9,
            LensManualDistortionAmount = 0,
            LensProfileEnable = 0,
            LensProfileSetup = "LensDefaults",
            LuminanceNoiseReductionContrast = 0,
            LuminanceNoiseReductionDetail = 50,
            LuminanceSmoothing = 0,
            ParametricDarks = 8,
            ParametricHighlightSplit = 75,
            ParametricHighlights = 2,
            ParametricLights = 15,
            ParametricMidtoneSplit = 50,
            ParametricShadowSplit = 25,
            ParametricShadows = 9,
            PerspectiveAspect = 0,
            PerspectiveHorizontal = 0,
            PerspectiveRotate = 0,
            PerspectiveScale = 100,
            PerspectiveUpright = 0,
            PerspectiveVertical = 0,
            PostCropVignetteAmount = 0,
            PostCropVignetteFeather = 50,
            PostCropVignetteHighlightContrast = 0,
            PostCropVignetteMidpoint = 50,
            PostCropVignetteRoundness = 0,
            PostCropVignetteStyle = 1,
            ProcessVersion = "6.7",
            RedHue = 10,
            RedSaturation = -5,
            ShadowTint = 0,
            Shadows2012 = 37,
            SharpenDetail = 25,
            SharpenEdgeMasking = 0,
            SharpenRadius = 1,
            Sharpness = 0,
            SplitToningBalance = 0,
            SplitToningHighlightHue = 0,
            SplitToningHighlightSaturation = 0,
            SplitToningShadowHue = 0,
            SplitToningShadowSaturation = 0,
            ToneCurveName2012 = "Black-Mamba_FLP.co",
            ToneCurvePV2012 = {
                0,
                33,
                47,
                38,
                88,
                73,
                116,
                131,
                143,
                179,
                202,
                216,
                255,
                243,
            },
            ToneCurvePV2012Blue = {
                0,
                0,
                255,
                255,
            },
            ToneCurvePV2012Green = {
                0,
                0,
                255,
                255,
            },
            ToneCurvePV2012Red = {
                0,
                0,
                255,
                255,
            },
            VignetteAmount = -7,
            VignetteMidpoint = 46,
            WhiteBalance = "As Shot",
            Whites2012 = 23,
            orientation = "BC",
        },
```

2: Implement all the method that Lightroom use to apply the presets, you can use libraries like [this](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) in help

3: you need a method that remap all preset setting as variables and applies the filter

Comment: Any help for the same task in 2022? @silverstorm :)